# Function not found in r

Tags: r, function, csv, matrix, sum

So I am trying to read a 49*49 matrix from a csv and calculate the sum. But I encounter a function not found error inspite of my csv getting recognized.

```
w <- read.csv(file="matrix.csv", header=F, sep=",");
sum <- 0
for(i in 1:49)
for(j in 1:49)
   sum = sum +w(i,j);
```

Here w is the 49*49 matrix .
I get an error saying function 'w' not found in R but I can view the w matrix in r.

Comment: There are syntax errors. Those parentheses should be brackets `w[i,j]` not `w(i,j)`, and the for loops should be `for ( i in 1:49) { sum = sum + w[i,j]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling R to invoke the function `w` when you subscript with parens.  That's a function call syntax.

Matrix and data frame indexing is with square brackets `[]`:

```
sum <- 0
for(i in 1:49)
for(j in 1:49)
   sum = sum +w[i,j];
```

Better to not use the name `sum` because it exists.  And in fact it does exactly what you want without any explicit loops:

```
sum(w)
```